# Test de eliminación con framework laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy tratando de realizar un test para eliminar un objeto de la bd, pero tengo no sé cómo realizarlo

Estoy utilizando la  ruta y buscando el objeto que quiero eliminar, pero no se realiza la eliminación, agradecería una pronta ayuda

El código del function del test

```
public function testDeleteFurgon(){
    $chofer =  Chofer::where('id', '=', '1')->first();
    $this->be($chofer);

    $furgon = Furgon::all()->find('1');
    $this->call('GET','furgon/1/destroy');
    $this->assertNull(Furgon::all()->find($furgon->patente));

}
```

Ruta:

```
Route::resource('furgon','FurgonController');
Route::get('furgon/{id}/destroy', ['uses' => 'FurgonController@destroy', 'as' => 'furgon.destroy']);
```

Función controlador:

```
public function destroy($id)   {
    $furgon = Furgon::find($id);
    $furgon->delete();
    return redirect()->route('furgon.index');
```

}

Comment: Pero analizaste el problema? te llega bien $id a destroy? no llega nada? llega bien pero cuando haces el find() no lo trae? anda verificando con dd(). Y mostranos el modelo si podes

Comment: Sí borra con el controlador, pero necesito hacerlo desde las pruebas y corre el test, pero no hace la eliminación

Answer (score 0):

En la función testDeleteFurgon() , lo puedes hacer de esta manera:

En vez de hacer un request de tipo GET, haces un request de tipo **DELETE** y no olvides pasar el valor del csrf token como tercer parámetro.

```
$this->call('DELETE','/furgon/1,['_token' => csrf_token()]);
```

Dejame saber si te funciona.

Answer (score 0):

El error podría estar en el la linea del `Furgon::all()->find($furgon->patente)`. El método `find` realiza la búsqueda por el `id` y tú estás pasando la patente. A no ser que sean iguales los attributes de `patente` y `id`.

Prueba con `Furgon::where('patente', '=', $furgon->patente)->first();`. Avísame como te va con eso.

Y prueba lo que dice Carlos.